# Oracle SQL null plus number give a null value

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm doing some calculation using (+ operations), but i saw that i have some null result, i checked the data base, and i found myself doing something like `number+number+nul+number+null+number...=null` . and this a problem for me.

there is any suggestion for my problem? how to solve this king for problems ?
thanks

Comment: Use `NVL` function to substitue null with some other value, say 0.

Comment: @Horrendous_Space_Kablooie, you should put this as the answer.  Because this is what they need to do.  There is no other option

Comment: Perfect (Y) it help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My preference is to use ANSI standard constructs:

```
select coalesce(n1, 0) + coalesce(n2, 0) + coalesce(n3, 0) + . . .
```

`NVL()` is specific to Oracle.  `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard and available in almost all databases.

Comment: yes it's a good suggestion, maybe one of the best, now i know there are two options NVL() and COALESCE() but this last is standard. thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 4):

You need to make those values 0 if they are null, you could use [nvl](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) function, like

```
 SELECT NVL(null, 0) + NVL(1, 0) from dual;
```

where the first argument of NVL would be your column.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like `NVL` to cast a null into a value, such as 0.

```
select NULL + 5 from dual;
```

Will return `null`.

```
select NVL(NULL, 0) + 5 from dual;
```

Will return `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized none of the answers mentioned what COALESCE() or NVL() is, I'd like to clarify since it can be confusing (I initially thought they were conjunction functions).

So suppose you want to select the full address of places in your table, you have 2 fields - AddressLine1 and AddressLine2. Assume "AddressLine1 " is always NOT NULL, and "AddressLine2" can be NULL. Then you may want to write something like this:

```
(SQL Server):
SELECT AddressLine1 + COALESCE(AddressLine2, '')
FROM   Places
```

So that for the entries that AddressLine2= NULL, this wouldn't return a NULL for it.

P.S. I wonder why the plus operation is designed this way in SQL, looks really counterintuitive.

Comment: `''` actually _is_ `NULL` in Oracle, so you would be adding a `NULL` to `Address` if `Address2` was `NULL`... Besides, string concatenation in Oracle is done using the `||` operator, not `+`. Unless, of course, `Address` and `Address2` are numbers in your example.